# Standard user to run Firerfox instead of shell like GNOME Shell or KDE Plasma

Tags: startup

I need to make a user than runs only one graphical program instead of loading the shell. It doesn't need to be restricted enough to reset all the settings every time the user logs out like regular guest account, but I just need it to run Firefox and save passwords if the user does, etc.

Bonus points if pressing the power button allows user to shutdown/restart/etc.

I'm pretty sure that similar questions has been asked before, but I can't craft by Google-fu to find them.